# Can I call shutdown twice on a file descriptor in C language?

Tags: c, file, sockets, networking, file-descriptor

I am using c .
I have fd1 as a file descriptor, can I call like this twice?

```
main () {
....
shutdown(fd1, SHUT_WR);
....
shutdown(fd1, SHUT_WR);
....
}
```

I personally think it works because fd1 has not been really free yet. Just want somebody to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the return value of the second call - [`shutdown(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) probably returns `-1` - and check the value of [`errno(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html).

Comment: So shutdown(2) still works and the result is probably -1 ? I'm just worried if shutdown(2) can crash my program by sending some kind of signal, like SIGPIPE ...

Comment: No, returning `-1` means it didn't work, it's the **error return value**. That doesn't mean you should write your programs so you don't know the state of the socket when you poke at it.

Comment: So will the 2nd call kill the program ?

Comment: @tsubasa: No, the second call won't kill the program: it will (almost certainly) simply return -1 with errno set to EBADF - as you could establish by testing for yourself the return value of the function.

Comment: thank you much, that's all i need to know. my program is getting so complicated that i can't test it simply.

Answer (score 1):

On my version of Linux and glibc, I can call `shutdown` multiple times on the same open socket. It will happily return 0 until the socket is actually torn down in that direction and will then return -1 with `errno == ENOTCONN`. It will not return `EBADF` until you `close` the FD and then you shouldn't still be using that FD anyway.

This fact is actually pretty useful, since you can call shutdown in a loop in order to detect that the connection has been torn down one way or another. `epoll`ing for errors on the socket appears to wake it up at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it once to shutdown the output and again to shutdown the input, or vice versa. Calling it twice to shutdown the output certainly won't send two FINs, whatever else it may do. Calling it twice to shutdown the input can't do anything twice either. So neither of those can possibly have any actual point.

NB You can't call it on a *file* descriptor at all. You can call it on a *socket* descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `shutdown` simply initiates a TCP level shutdown sequence. The socket descriptor is never released for reuse until you call `close` on it.

You can call `shutdown` as often as you like, though it's likely that subsequent calls will result in an error.

Call `close` when you are done with the socket.